# How do I call a row number by using a variable in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I recorded a macro, which I want to modify in order to use it automatically in multiple ranges in the Excel worksheet. Here's the code:

```
Sub Macro1()

For i = 6 To 22370 Step 5

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "tute.xlsm" _
    , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
Rows(i:i).Select
Range("D" & i).Activate
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Range("D" & i).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "xyz"
Range("A"&"i-1":"C"&"i-1").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("A" & i).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("E" & i).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C*R[4]C"
Range("E" & i).Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("E37:AO37"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("E"&i:"AO"&i).Select
Range("D" & i).Select
Next
End Sub
```

I would like to use the variable "i" to call specific rows, as in the case of *Rows(i:i).Select* or a range such as *Range("E"&i:"AO"&i).Select*, but I get an error message: "Expected: list separator or )"

Can you help pls?

Thank you in advance

Comment: variables can't be inside double quotes. Non-variables (strings) can't be outside of double quotes. So `Range("A"&"i-1":"C"&"i-1")` should be `Range("A" & i-1 & ":C" & i-1)` (as one example). And `Range("E"&i:"AO"&i).Select` should be `Range("E" & i ":AO" & i).Select`

Comment: Also when using `Rows()` and only selecting a single row, you don't need the colon. So just `Rows(i).Select`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides my comments above, here's a quick rewrite to get rid of all of the superfluous `.Activate` and `.Select` lines. Those are for humans, VBA doesn't need to select something before acting on it. It can just act on it directly.

```
Sub Macro1()

    'This line shouldn't be in your for loop otherwise you save this workbook like 4000 times
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="tute.xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

    For i = 6 To 22370 Step 5        
        
        'No reason to select the row since we just go ahead and activate a particular cell immediately afterwords        
        'Rows(i:i).Select

        'No reason to "Activate" the cell. We can just shift it down without highlighting the thing for the user
        'Range("D" & i).Activate
        Range("D" & i).Insert Shift:=xlDown

        'No need to .Select. Just change the formula directly.
        'Range("D" & i).Select
        Range("D" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "xyz"

        'Again, no need to .Select. And we can do the copy/paste in one line
        'Range("A"&"i-1":"C"&"i-1").Select
        'Selection.Copy
        'Range("A" & i).Select
        'ActiveSheet.Paste
        Range("A" & i-1 & ":C" & i-1).Copy Destination:=Range("A" & i)

        'Removing superfluous select again
        'Range("E" & i).Select

        'Also superfluous code that isn't needed
        'Application.CutCopyMode = False
        'Application.CutCopyMode = False

        
        Range("E" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C*R[4]C"
        'Range("E" & i).Select
        Range("E" & i).AutoFill Destination:=Range("E37:AO37"), Type:=xlFillDefault

        'Superfluous selects
        'Range("E"&i:"AO"&i).Select
        'Range("D" & i).Select
    Next
End Sub
```

And then cleaned up to remove all of that:

```
Sub Macro1()
    
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="tute.xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

    For i = 6 To 22370 Step 5

        'Shift column D for this line down a row (add a new empty cell for this line)      
        Range("D" & i).Insert Shift:=xlDown

        'Change the value to xyz of column D for this line (the new cell)
        Range("D" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "xyz"

        'Copy three lines in column A:C and paste 1 line down
        Range("A" & i-1 & ":C" & i-1).Copy Destination:=Range("A" & i)
        
        'Change the formula in column E for this line
        Range("E" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C*R[4]C"
        
        'Not sure if this is what you are actually after here. Perhaps that should be `Range("E" & i & ":AO" & i)?`
        Range("E" & i).AutoFill Destination:=Range("E37:AO37"), Type:=xlFillDefault

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help! It worked perfectly

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out!